# Editing a child JSON element value with jq

Tags: command-line, replace, json, jq

I'm trying to use jq in order to change a child's value. For instance, I want to change the value of "test2" from ["yo", "bye"] to ["hi"].

```
{
   "title": "hello",
   "body": {
       "test1": 123,
       "test2": [
           "yo",
           "bye"  
       ]
   }
}
```

So far I could only change values of keys that are childs of the root. I can't figure out how to take this and go to .body.test2 instead of title:

```
cat test.conf | jq 'to_entries | map(if .key == "title" then . + {"value":"hello world"} else . end) | from_entries' > test2.conf
```

Comment: Would `jq '{ body: (.body + { test2: ["hi"] }) }'` do it?

Comment: `jq '.body.test2 = ["hi"]'` will do it

Comment: @glennjackman Just posted your comment as a community answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*(Posting [@glennjackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman) comment as a community answer to prevent system from autodeleting the question)*

> `jq '.body.test2 = ["hi"]'` will do it

Answer (score 0):

The command

```bash
jq '.body.test2 = ["hi"]' test.conf >test2.conf
```

... would do it, but assuming you may want to have better control over the operation without having to hard-code the `test2` key name and the text that you're adding:

```
printf '%s\n' "line 1" "line 2" "line 3" |
jq -SR . |
jq --arg section test2 '.body[$section] = [inputs]' test.conf - >test2.conf
```

This takes arbitrary lines of text (three lines in the example, but in theory, you would be able to `cat` a text document here or pass one directly as an argument to the following `jq` command) and converts these into separate JSON strings using `jq -SR .`.  The pipeline then passes them to a second `jq` invocation that inserts them as an array under the correct section under the `body` key.

Using `-` as the second input filename with the final `jq` invocation causes the utility to insert the JSON strings from the standard input stream in place of `inputs` in the `jq` expression.

Given the document in the question, the above pipeline would produce the following JSON document in `test2.conf`:

```json
{
  "title": "hello",
  "body": {
    "test1": 123,
    "test2": [
      "line 1",
      "line 2",
      "line 3"
    ]
  }
}
```